# Combining unbalanced rows into a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, append

I am working on a project to simulate missing data and run regressions on the sampled data. 
Here is what I have so far.
    library(MASS)

```
#specifying the covariance matrix
sigma <- matrix(c(1,.7,.49,.343,.2401,.7,1,.7,.49,.343,.49,.7,1,.7,.49,.343,.49,
              .7,1,.7,.2401,.343,.49,.7,1),5,5,byrow=TRUE)

#generating the data
data <- mvrnorm(n=1000, c(5,5.25,5.5,5.75,6), sigma)
split(data,)

#specifying the missing data mechanism for MCAR
LogoddsratioMCAR <- -.5
OddsRatioMCAR <-exp(LogoddsratioMCAR)
OddsMCAR <- OddsRatioMCAR/(1+OddsRatioMCAR)
Probability2 <- 1-OddsMCAR
Probability3 <- Probability2 - OddsMCAR*(Probability2)
Probability4 <- Probability3 - OddsMCAR*(Probability3)
Probability5 <- Probability4 - OddsMCAR*(Probability4)

#sampling from each column
dataframe <- as.data.frame(data)
dataMCAR1 <- dataframe$V1
dataMCAR2 <- dataframe$V2[sample(1:nrow(data),Probability2*nrow(data))]
dataMCAR3 <- dataframe$V3[sample(1:nrow(data),Probability3*nrow(data))]
dataMCAR4 <- dataframe$V4[sample(1:nrow(data),Probability4*nrow(data))]
dataMCAR5 <- dataframe$V5[sample(1:nrow(data),Probability5*nrow(data))]
```

Now i need to add NA's to dataMCAR2-dataMCAR5 in order for the lists to be of the same length. I would like to combine them into one dataframe and run regressions on them.

How would I append those NA's to the lists?

Comment: does [this](https://github.com/raredd/rawr/blob/master/R/utils.R#L1600:L1606) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. dataMCAR1 has the length of 1000. So you want to have the same length for the other vectors (e.g., dataMCAR2). Here, I concatenated each vector and NAs in `lapply`. Then, I bound all five vectors using `cbind` and created a data frame. Finally, I changed column names using the names from the list (i.e., ana)

```
ana <- mget(ls(pattern = "^dataMCAR\\d+"))

bob <- as.data.frame(Reduce(cbind,
                        lapply(ana, function(x) c(x, rep(c(NA), times = (1000 - length(x)))))
                            )
                    )

colnames(bob) <- names(ana)

#  dataMCAR1 dataMCAR2 dataMCAR3 dataMCAR4 dataMCAR5
#1  3.492947  6.702115  4.743988  6.330211  6.257005
#2  4.637356  5.322731  4.916232  6.209659  7.619699
#3  2.967167  4.397137  5.445473  6.632309  6.844667
#4  4.484144  4.814281  5.060921  5.357306  4.831958
#5  6.245234  5.471267  4.959116  5.975332  6.243439
#6  5.334700  4.122378  6.671627  6.529121  7.354149

#summary(bob)
#   dataMCAR1       dataMCAR2       dataMCAR3       dataMCAR4       dataMCAR5    
#Min.   :1.465   Min.   :2.141   Min.   :2.223   Min.   :3.253   Min.   :3.249  
#1st Qu.:4.334   1st Qu.:4.606   1st Qu.:4.886   1st Qu.:5.106   1st Qu.:5.412  
#Median :5.005   Median :5.336   Median :5.616   Median :5.795   Median :6.064  
#Mean   :5.000   Mean   :5.305   Mean   :5.550   Mean   :5.783   Mean   :6.041  
#3rd Qu.:5.657   3rd Qu.:5.957   3rd Qu.:6.225   3rd Qu.:6.487   3rd Qu.:6.697  
#Max.   :8.168   Max.   :8.955   Max.   :8.208   Max.   :8.043   Max.   :8.740  
#                NA's   :378     NA's   :613     NA's   :759     NA's   :850
```